# lvalue required as left operand of assignment - resto da divisão

Tags: c, c++, operadores

Estou com um problema para fazer resto da divisão. Deu esse erro:

> value required as left operand of assignment

Como resolvo isso?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int x;
printf("informe o numero inteiro: \n");
scanf("%d",&x);
if (x>0)
    {
    printf("numero positivo ");
    }
    else {
        printf("numero negativo ");
    }
if (x % 2 = 0)
{
    printf("e par");
}
    else {
        printf("e impar");
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: O erro é que você usou o operador de atribuição `=` em vez do de comparação `==`.

Comment: Não esqueça de verificar se o programa fornece o resultado que você espera para x = 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O sinal de comparação que irá funcionar, `=` é atribuição, `==` é comparação. Em uma atribuição não pode ter uma expressão do lado esquerdo, só uma variável, deu sorte desta vez, o compilador pegou o erro, se tivesse só uma variável funcionaria, mas estaria errado.

```
if (x % 2 == 0)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Math/Even.c).